# What's the difference between Process[] and Process()[]

Tags: c#

I was doing research for my pattern scanner but I came to this problem.

The pattern scanner that I saw needed a handler of the process but the way I'm doing it

```
Process[] P = Process.GetProcessesByName("pName");
```

doesn't have `P.Handle` and I went to msdn but there it says it have. But why mine doesn't?

What is the difference between those two lines of code?

```
Process P = Process.GetProcessesByName("pName")[0];
Process[] P = Process.GetProcessesByName("pName");
```

Comment: `GetProcessesByName` returns an array of `Process`.  [Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) has the `Handle` property.  So you need to select one of the returned `Process` objects and call `.Handle` on that.

Comment: Note the `[0]` on the end of the first line, this returns the first element in the array.

Comment: ok thank you it was kind of obvious for me but im kinda dumb just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets the first process that has a name of "pName":

```
Process P = Process.GetProcessesByName("pName")[0];
```

Note that this will cause an "index out of bounds" exception if there aren't any.

This gets a list (or an array, actually) of all processes that have a name of "pName":

```
Process[] P = Process.GetProcessesByName("pName");
```

Note that this won't cause an exception if there aren't any; it'll just return an empty array.

With the latter, you can index it just like the former, if you want the first match:

```
Process[] P = Process.GetProcessesByName("pName");
if (P.Length > 0)
{
    Process process = P[0];  //Get the first one
}
else
{
    Log("No such process!");
}
```

Or (the way I would do it) use LINQ:

```
Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName("pName").FirstOrDefault();
if (p != null) 
{
    //Do something with the process
}
```